# Whether the p-adic power series $\sum \frac{(n!)^n}{1+(n!)^{2n}} x^n$ converges p-adically

Tags: number-theory, convergence-divergence, p-adic-number-theory

**p-adic convergence:**

The p-adic power series $\sum \frac{1}{n!} x^n$ is divergent.

But what about the p-adic power series $\sum \frac{(n!)^n}{1+(n!)^{2n}} x^n$?

Does it converge p-adically?

**Answer:**

we have $a_n=\frac{(n!)^n}{1+(n!)^{2n}} $.

Now,

$\left|\frac{(n!)^{n}}{1+(n!)^{2n}} \right|_p \sim \left|\frac{(n!)^{n}}{1} \right|_p=\left|(n!)^n \right|_p==p^{-n  \ \text{ord}_p(n!)} \to 0$ as $ n \to \infty$.

Thus the p-adic power series $\sum \frac{(n!)^n}{1+(n!)^{2n}} x^n$ converges p-adically.

Is my calculation correct?

Please confirm me.

If my calculation is correct, how can I generalise the power series?

That means , how to extend the coefficient $\frac{(n!)^n}{1+(n!)^{2n}}$ into more **general form** ?

Comment: Also consider the (linear, possibly negative) $p$-valuation of $x$. (Or specify what $x$ is at least, so that the framework is complete.) The question about the "general form" is not clear. Note that there is so much "power of convergence" in $(n!)^n$ which makes things clear.

Comment: @dan_fulea, by general form I mean how to give general form of the coefficient $ \frac{(n!)^n}{1+(n!)^{2n}}$ so that it is a particular case. For example if I consider the series $ \sum \frac{(p(n)!)^n}{q+(p(n)!)^{2n}} x^n$, where $p(n)$ is a polynomial in $n$ and $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ so that the p-adic series still converges

Comment: It's not standard terminology to say that these power series are "convergent" or "divergent" without further qualification. Rather, each power series has a well-defined *radius of convergence*, and I would assume that's what one wants to find. Or, are just asking whether the series at $x=1$ is convergent? That's what you seem to be testing. Please clarify.